# yandex xml api keeping saying Request limit exceed

Tags: yandex, yandex-api

on 22.12.20 I got email from yandex.webmaster [image]

from January 27:0 query. i try find hour limit for 24 hour then i got

```
<time-interval from="2021-02-01 20:00:00 +0000" to="2021-02-01 21:00:00 +0000">0</time-interval>
```

0 value, i can't use a single query in every hour. Is xml.yandex.com shut down?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your websites to https://webmaster.yandex.ru/ and for each website you have some number of requests.